# Looking to convert Excel VBA macro into Google Sheet app script, the script compares dates and autofills/deletes columns

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

I'm trying to convert this working Excel macro script into Google Apps Script (which I'm completely new too!):

```
Sub Booking3Days()

Dim firstDate As Date, secondDate As Date, n As Integer

BookingDate = Cells(1, 2)
TodayDate = Date

n = DateDiff("d", BookingDate, TodayDate)

        If n > 0 Then
        For n = 1 To n
        Range("E1:E90").AutoFill Destination:=Range("E1:F90")
        Range("B1:B90").Delete shift:=xlToLeft
        Next n
        End If
End Sub
```

What it is doing is I have a booking sheet that in Cols B to D has 3 consecutive days with the day's date in cells B1, C1 & D1. What I want to happen is when the file is opened the macro runs and compares today's date with cell B1 and if that date is past then autofill col D into col E to create the next day in the list and then delete the oldest date (Col B). The FOR loop then repeats this for every day until today's date is in Col B.

Struggling to get all the elements working in Google Apps Script however! Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi, Niknak! When a macro is recorded is sheets, it is saved as an apps script file. After recording it click on  "edit script". I recommend you to learn some basic `Java Script`, which is the language that apps script is based on. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview  . Best whises

Comment: Hi ninjaCoderr, That's exactly what I ended up doing. Basically recording the bits one by one in the macro and then spliced them together into one. I cheated a bit getting the number of days for the FOR loop by getting this value calculated in a hidden row on the spreadsheet but this was the code I ended up with for the macro and it works: